# GAE downloading log with LogQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

My application generates many, many log messages. I would like to download only messages in a specific time interval. I looked around and LogQuery seems to be a good choice.

It seems like LogQuery, as specified here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/LogQuery.Builder

, let one specify a start and end time in milliseconds.

However, there is no such method `withStartTimeMillis` or `withEndTimeMillis` in the GAE library that I downloaded from the web. I'm using GAE SDK 1.7.1. There are only `withStartTimeUSec` and `withEndTimeUsec` which deal in microsecond.

What's amiss here?

Answer (score 0):

[`LogQuery.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/LogQuery.Builder) has both methods: `withStartTimeMillis(long startTimeMillis)` and `withStartTimeUsec(long startTimeUsec)`.

Also, the current version is 1.8.1, so you should upgrade to that before starting to resolve errors.